# iOS : background image black instead of requested image?

Tags: ios, background, uiimage

I'm trying to set the background to an image.

code:

```
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myPic"]]];
```

My original plan was to set the self.window to the background image and then have the other views be clear. (Using self.window in the app delegate) But after that turned our to give me a plain black screen (??) , I moved and adjusted the code to my RootViewController. I'm still getting a plain black screen. I tried using a few different images, yet I'm getting the same result on all of them. Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Would a UIImageView not work better?

Comment: What I really want to do it set the background image for the entire app. (in the AppDelegate) and then have the other views be transparent. I would rather not use a UIImageView, but set the image to the view itself. That's the route I tried originally, but I thought maybe I hadn't done the transparency correctly, so I set it directly to the view. Still blackness. Ugh.

Comment: Deleted my first comment by mistake, I think its because your missing your pic file extension. myPic should probably be myPic.png

Comment: Try using [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; and see if it sets the background blue. If it does, you know there is a problem with the UIColor object being returned in the code that you posted. If it doesn't, then there is a problem some where else.

Comment: @Bushbert - your answer was the right one. It was a .jpg file. The original one I was using was a .png and then I changed it to a different one. If you change your comment into an answer, I can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image name "myPic" should contain the file extension i.e. myPic.jpg